# Convert an SQL Query as JSON in Oracle 11g within Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, json, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Within Oracle APEX v4.2 I have a fairly large table with around 40 columns and up to 50 rows where I need to fetch using SQL and convert each row to a JSON object.

I am using Oracle 11gR2 and need to use this JSON object within javascript in order to perform some graphing requirements.

With Oracle SQL query having a limitation of varchar2(4000) inside APEX, how I can I accomplish the conversion of all rows into JSON? I was looking at a result as follows to use in JavaScript, i.e.:

```
[{"col1": "value1", "col2": "value2", ....., "col40": "value40"}, {"col1": "value21", "col2": "value22", ....., "col40": "value400"}, etc]
```

Comment: Use [clob](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50998) data type instead of varchar2. Clob size can be several gigabytes.

Comment: Thanks - actually ended up going that way.

Comment: The 4k limitation is for storage, in plsql the max length is 32k

Comment: Thanks. Ended up writing a function that basically constructed my JSON object via a cursor which I returned to a page item in Oracle APEX using varchar2(32767). I will be answering my own question based on this.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up writing a function that basically constructed my JSON object via a cursor which I returned to a page item in Oracle APEX using varchar2(32767) within my pl/sql function.

Comment: Can you share the function?